# Perfect forwarding function parameters to function pointer: What about passing by value?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I have a data structure that provides access to its elements, and some loop logic for how to iterate over them.
I need to call different functions inside the loop(s). These functions all take a data element as first parameter, but shall be allowed to have any number of additional parameters.
So far, this sounds like a typical case for perfect fowarding, so my attempt is this (generic example):

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void looper(
    const DataStructure& dataStruct,
    void (*func)(const DataElement&, Ts ...),
    Ts&& ... args
){
    for (Index i{0}; i<dataStruct.someSize(); ++i )
        func( dataStruct.elem(i), std::forward<Ts>(args) ... );
}
```

However, say I want to call it with a function that takes parameters by value (like primitive types), then I quickly have a problem.

```
void myFunc( const DataElement&, int ){
    /* do something */
}
```

If I call the looper function and pass a variable of type `int`, it will always be recognised as an `int&`, and then I have an `inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int' and 'int&'`:

```
DataStructure dataStruct;
int myInt {0};
looper( dataStruct, myFunc, myInt ); // <--- this line will cause a compiler error
```

That's a very descriptive error message, and I know I could, for example, solve it by making `myFunc` take a `const int&`.

However, I'd rather be able to just write any function, which also may take parameters by value, and pass its pointer to the looper. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not use range based for loop or ::std::for_each? Note that you are not forwarding anything because you are not using universal references for `Ts`.

Comment: The example I gave here is strongly simplified. In reality, the traversal of elements is more complicated than one simple loop, so neither a range based for loop or ```std::for_each``` will do. Otherwise I'd use them, of course.
And about your second point: I guess you're referencing the function pointer signature? That one cannot take universal references. But right in the line below, the parameters the looper actually takes, are taken as universal references.

Comment: Note that perfect forwarding may not be appropriate here.  If the function called in the first iteration of your loop moves from one of its parameters then that object's data won't be available for the call in the second iteration of the loop.  For something like this it may be better to use a good ol' lvalue-reference-to-const instead.

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks. Moving wouldn't make sense in the actual application, so it's not gonna happen, but I'd still prefer my code to reflect the intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Args` will be deduced *twice*, once for the function signature, and once for the parameters. They do not necessarily need to be exactly the same: the argument is deduced as `int&`, since it is deduced from a local variable, but it does not correspond to the function signature (which is `int`).

You can split them, like this:

```
template<typename... Ts_fun_args, typename... Ts_param_args>
void looper(
    const DataStructure& dataStruct,
    void (*func)(const DataElement&, Ts_fun_args ...),
    Ts_param_args&& ... args
){
    for (Index i{0}; i<dataStruct.someSize(); ++i )
        func( dataStruct.elem(i), std::forward<Ts_param_args>(args) ... );
}
```

Note that `Ts_fun_args` needs to be convertable to `Ts_param_args`. If you have a function signature taking a `int&` for example, you cannot pass a `const int&`. This might lead to a confusing error message.